# ServiceStack 4.0.3 has missing DLL's after been installed from Nuget

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, servicestack

I'm trying to figure out how to use ServiceStack.
So I downloaded the `ServiceStack.Host.AspNet` pack to try understand where to start.
But for some reason I can't compile the solution.
I have a missing references, like:

`using ServiceStack.CacheAccess;`
and
`using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;`

As I understood from google they have some issue with v 4.0.3.
How can I make it work?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the compile error that you get?

Answer (score 3):

Ok looks the `ServiceStack.Host.AspNet` and `ServiceStack.Host.Mvc` templates haven't been updated to match v4 yet. In which case you would need to install v3 if you wanted to use the templates:

```
Install-Package ServiceStack.Host.AspNet -Version 3.9.71
```

Here are some more [NuGet instructions for v3](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3).

But if you wanted to use v4, it would be more beneficial to skip the templates which is just the binaries, with an AppHost and Service already configured and just install ServiceStack:

```
Install-Package ServiceStack
```

And follow the [Create your first service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) wiki to configure ServiceStack manually, which gives you a better idea of how ServiceStack works and will provide less friction in updates as only be binaries will be updated.

Comment: Thanks, will do that..!